# How to create an Azure server to publish clickonce?

Tags: azure, visual-studio, clickonce

I'm trying to publish the wpf app using ClickOnce.

I notice an option to set a web site.

How do I create/deploy a website like this to let users download ClickOnce?

Because I want to make it accessible to anyone, not only via FTP.

If possible, could I do this using Azure?

[image]

Comment: Check if this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/37db1d/deploying-wpf-application-with-clickonce-deployment-techniques/) helps.

Comment: @PravallikaKV Thanks, but what blocks me is how to create a `web server` to publish it.